# facebook login bug using fb php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework

My problem is the following.
I have a website 
http://de.gamercharts.com/

You can connect with facebook(if you don't have an account,an account will be created).
After this ,if you logout from the site ,you are logged out from facebook too.
Everything is ok so far.
The problem is that if I am logged out of the site (let's call the site GC) and logged out of facebook ,when I click "connect with facebook" on the site,I get logged in on the site,instead of being prompted to the facebook login screen.
When I print the user ,I see that even though I am logged out of facebook,I still have the user id.
Why does this happen,and how can I fix it ?
Thanx a lot to anyone who takes the time to answer.
For the record I am using Zend ,although I don't think it's relevant.
I did not implement the facebook login myself,I am continuing the work of someone else.

Comment: This is a well known problem. Can you paste your facebook logout script?

Comment: I don't handle the facebook logout myself.I do a redirect to facebook like so:https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fde.gamercharts.com%2Flogout&access_token=367142350026907%7C44c1128426159aa61f9432c17bf16082.     You can pass a url to this function,url which is our own logout function,which deletes the GC session.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I still see my FB user id when I am logged out of facebook.I just want to make my question more obvious.

Comment: are you using facebook php sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused due to existence of `Facebook Session Variables` in your domain/site, even after logging out from facebook and your site. When someone logs out from your site, one should take care to destroy all the sessions[even facebook sessions]. For destroying facebook sessions in your domain/site, you can make use of the function `destroySession();` [provided in the facebook php sdk] in your logout script.

```
 $config = array();
 $config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
 $config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $logout = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'url to be redirected after logout'));
 $facebook->destroySession(); // To destroy facebook Sessions
 $session_destroy(); //To destroy sessions of your site
 header("Location:$logout");
```

P.S Don't forget to include or call session_start() in the script

Comment: Thanx John.Your answer pointed me in the right direction,but the problem is that my facebook object does not have the destroySession() method.I checked this before posting this answer as I suspected it had something to do with facebook's sessions.These are all the methods available to my facebook object.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => setAppId
    [2] => getAppId
    [3] => setApiSecret
    [4] => getApiSecret
    [5] => setFileUploadSupport
    [6] => useFileUploadSupport
    [7] => setAccessToken
    [8] => getAccessToken
    [9] => getSignedRequest
    [10] => getUser
    [11] => getLoginUrl
    [12] => getLogoutUrl
    [13] => getLoginStatusUrl
    [14] => api
)

Comment: I read about this method ,destroySession in other parts,but can't seem to find it.From what I read in the documentation it seems that you just have to make the user click on the facebook logout url,and that's it.This is what it says,maybe you understand it differently."The SDK can be used to support authentication your site using the users' Facebook account. On the server-side, the SDK provides helper-methods to authentication, requesting permissions, and logout. This functionality is provided by the Facebook::getUser(), Facebook::getLoginUrl() and Facebook::getLogoutUrl() methods."

Comment: I have tried deleting all the cookies from code.I tried this  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}

Comment: It did not work.But I notice that if I use Chrome's Delete All Cookies option,it works as expected.

Comment: By as expected I mean that when I logout from the site,it logs me out from facebook,than I delete cookies with chrome,and after that when I try to 'connect with facebook' I am redirected to the facebook login screen.Any ideas what I am doing wrong in deleting the facebook cookies ?

Comment: Facebook docs sometimes are too confusing and are not clear. Cookies also play a part. Facebook set their cookies in your domain to monitor user details, app details etc. Deleting those cookies is one of the tricks but not a permanent solution. In fact facebook is monitoring your domain by setting sessions and cookies. I have updated the answer. Copy those lines in a file named logout.php(just a suggestion) and call the logout script whenever user clicks the logout button. This should do the trick. If this doesn't work or you have any more doubts feel free to ask..:)

Comment: Don't worry about `destroySession()` function. Even though its not listed in your facebook object, it is an available function in facebook php sdk and you can use it without any hesitation. ;)

Comment: Hi John.That's what I wanted to do,to put the code you provided in the logout.php .The destroy session function really is not there.I have another question related to php/facebook,if you have time,please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511776/how-to-post-programatically-to-your-own-facebook-page

Comment: In that question I post an url in which I list all of the methods of the sdk ,FOR ANOTHER SITE,FOR MY PERSONAL SITE.the destroy session is present over there.I think it;s a sdk version problem.I will check to see the differences between the sdk's.THanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use facebook sdk, then you need use exception try-catch for checking if user is still logged in:

```
 1$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 2  'appId'  => you id,
 3  'secret' => you secret,
 4));
 5
 6// See if there is a user from a cookie
 7$user = $facebook->getUser();
 8
 9if ($user) {
10  try {
11    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
12    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
13  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
14    error_log($e);
15    $user = null;
16  }
17}
```

And after that you can get correct user id and other information from Facebook

---

Every time you need to request me-page. And if this page throw an error, then delete facebook user's data. User's id, and other facebook data stored in the cookies; when you logged out in the Facebook site, cookies for you site continue to be kept; your php-code will read this cookies:

```
1$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

and return user id.
With this code:

```
1$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

you check if this cookies is actuall, and if it isn't, you change it:

```
1$user = null;
```

All the matter in cookies

Comment: Well,I don't see how this answers my question.My question is ,how can the facebook api get a user id (my user id ,I chcecked) if I am logged out of facebook).